# What Performance Object in Performance Monitor will show Split IO/sec for USB flash drives?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7, windows-vista, usb-flash-drive, perfmon

I'm using a Windows XP desktop to test the I/O for a 4GB USB flash drive. I would like to use Performance Monitor to capture the statistics of the test, but neither the Physical Disk or the Logical Disk objects show the USB flash drive as a viable instance. I attempted to track the ***_Total*** and ***0 C:*** instances, but ***_Total*** only tracked the C: drive and ignored the USB drive.

Does anybody know what Performance Object I need to use to get Logical Disk type data from a USB flash drive?

**UPDATE:** I have some very specific data files that I am using for the tests that represent the real-world usage these drives will see. This is why I am trying to use perfmon to track the performance instead of a benchmark utility.

Comment: Odd. My XP machines do include extra counters for spinning disks attached via IDE/SATA->USB mass storage device adaptors, or did do last time I looked a few months ago, but I plugged a flash into my work laptop and it doesn't in this case. I'll try again later when I have access to a spare spinning disk to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the counters I was looking for are not available in Windows XP. They are in Vista and Windows 7 however. Since we are planning to upgrade our systems to Windows 7, I used that for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a utility such as HDtune from www.hdtune.com. It allows you to run tests on drives to see their bulk transfer rate and seek time.

I'm sure that there's a free version as well (have a hunt around for it).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately the software only does benchmarks, not realtime performance tracking.